# View Image via controller function with absolue Path Yii1

Tags: php, yii

I want to View Original Image when i click on thubnail image in gridview.

```
$file =  'http://localhost/myapp/upload/item_original/'.$model->image;
$type = 'image/jpg';
header('Content-Type:'.$type);
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
readfile($file);
```

i tried above code and it didn't work.
then i tried easyimage extension.

```
public function actionViewImg($id){
    $model = $this->loadModel($id);
Yii::import('application.extensions.easyimage.EasyImage');
$image = new Image('http://localhost/obhre/upload/item_original/1235.jpg'); //get the image
$image->save('upload/viewimg/1235.jpg');//save it to another folder
echo Yii::app()->easyImage->thumbOf('upload/viewimg/1235.jpg'); //view the image
}
```

above code is working if i put relative path.but not with the absolute path.
error is "Dont have a image"

Answer (score 0):

This code should work:

```
public function actionViewImg($id) 
{
    $model = $this->loadModel($id);
    $file = 'http://localhost/myapp/upload/item_original/'.$model->image;

    header('Content-Type: image/jpg');
    header('Content-Length: '.filesize($file));
    echo file_get_contents($file);

    exit;
}
```